# php soap passing complextype of complextype parameter

Tags: php, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a problem with passing data at this soap wsdl, I have a complextype of complextype

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LibIf">
<xs:complexType name="RuleParams">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Parameters" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfRuleParameter"/>
        <xs:element name="Result" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="RuleParams" nillable="true" type="tns:RuleParams"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfRuleParameter">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RuleParameter" nillable="true" type="tns:RuleParameter"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfRuleParameter" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfRuleParameter"/>
<xs:complexType name="RuleParameter">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Value" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="RuleParameter" nillable="true" type="tns:RuleParameter"/>
```

I tried to use stdClass() but it doesn't work.

```
$params = new \stdClass();
$params->RuleParams = new \stdClass();
$params->Parameters = new \stdClass();
$params->Result = true;
$RuleParameter1 = new \stdClass();
$RuleParameter1->Name = 'name';
$RuleParameter1->Value = 'value';
$RuleParameter2 = new \stdClass();
$RuleParameter2->Name = 'name2';
$RuleParameter2->Value = 'value2';
$ArrayOfRuleParameter = array($RuleParameter1,$RuleParameter2);
$params->RuleParams->Parameters->ArrayOfRuleParameter = (object) $ArrayOfRuleParameter;
```

Usually I use simpler web-services with less data.
in this case can I send a xml for struct the data?